# How to display specular spot in an object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am creating a sphere. The light source (ambient and diffuse lighting) works well. Only the specular light that doesn't show up in any part of the sphere.

The material code seems not working. I deleted the line and the result is also the same.

The result I want is the sphere rotates with white spot on it in order to look real.

Am I missing any required configuration for lighting?

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

[image]

```
float angle = 0.0f;

void initRendering(){
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
}

void draw(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glutSolidSphere(0.5, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();

    GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    GLfloat diffuseColor[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    GLfloat specularColor[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    GLfloat lightPosition[] = {0.0f, 5.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f};

    GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseColor);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularColor);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);

    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,  mat_specular);
    glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 100);

    angle+=0.1f;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

main(){
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Sphere");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    initRendering();
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: You should really not use the fixed function pipeline in 2017. This stuff is deprecated since a decade by now, and it has been completely removed from OpenGL core profiles.

Comment: @derhass Okay thanks. I think this will be the last. I still want to add specular spot with this existing style. Yeah, because I am required to do so.

Comment: Well, it boils down to the same thing: understanding the lighting model. I've no idea why you expect to see a specular highlight in the scene as you did set them up. I've also no idea what the rotation of the sphere should be good for.

Comment: @derhass Could you tell what's the requirement for specular highlight?

Comment: To see it, the light needs to be reflected in the viewer's direction.

Comment: @derhass How is it?

Answer (score 1):

The default for specular light is to *add* to the colour evaulated in the diffuse illumination step. The specular intensity is modulated by the specular set. *You've set this colour to "black"*, so it adds literally zero.

```
GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
// …
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,  mat_specular);
```

I'd start by actually not inhibiting the specular term.